# Не выводится переменная созданная в обработчике события jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему созданная в обработчике переменная не распространяется за его пределы?

Например, тут ничего не выведет:

```
 $('#search').on('keyup', function(){

     a = 'test';

 });

 alert(a); //ничего не выведет
```

А здесь выводит:

```
 $('#search').on('keyup', function(){

     a = 'test';
     alert(a); //окно test
 });
```

Comment: @Doofy Я нажимаю на клавиши и поидее должен срабатывать обработчик, который создаст переменную. Потом эта переменная за пределами скобок по идеи должна вывестисть

Comment: Асинхронщина же!

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, то глобальная между документами, а эта в потоке

Comment: @Doofy, никакой разницы. Глубинная причина -- непонимание асинхронщины что там, что тут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При нажатии кнопки работает только **функции** обработчика, код который написан после - отработал после *создания* обработчика.

`a` не существует до нажатия кнопки. Сначало выводится `alert`, а потом нажимаем любую кнопку в `#search` и `alert` с выводом `a` уже вспышку прохлебал

```
$('#search').on('keyup', function() {
    a = 'test';
    console.log(a); // test
});

console.log(a); // a is not defined
```

```js
$('#search').on('keyup', function() {
  a = this.value;
  f(a);
});

function f(a) {
  console.log(a);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<input id='search'>
```

---

Можно объявить переменную до обработчика, в обработчике ей назначить значение, а затем использовать где угодно

```js
a = null;

$('#search').on('keyup', function() {
  a = this.value;
});

$('button').click(function() {
  console.log(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<input id='search'>
<button>получить значение</button>
```

Comment: Я нажимаю на клавиши и по идее должен срабатывать обработчик, который создаст переменную. Потом эта переменная за пределами скобок  должна вывестисть, но не выводится

Comment: @Pavel, потому что при нажатии кнопки работает **только** функции обработчика, код который написан после - отработал после _создания_ обработчика

Comment: @Grundy, каефная формулировка. Можно запишу в ответ?

Comment: @Doofy А как из функции эту переменную вытащить?

Comment: @Pavel, никак :-)

Comment: @Doofy, попробуй :-)

Comment: @Doofy, это не поможет, так как при использовании _до_ вызова обработчика - значение все еще будет старое, что и логично

Comment: @Grundy, ну я имею ввиду вызывать её тоже обработчиком, но уже в другом месте :)

Comment: @Doofy, так еще больше заморочек :-) при нажатии на кнопку до ввода текста - он выведет null :-)

Comment: @Grundy, можно же не назначать. Это чтобы избавиться от ошибки

Comment: @Doofy, Тогда выведет undefined, а в strict mode, вообще упадет :-)